# to create a file in shell command (sed or other)

Tags: shell, sed

There is a file which i want to create  ,how to write a shell command in sed or other?

file '/home/debian/01.flv'
file '/home/debian/02.flv'
file '/home/debian/03.flv'
file '/home/debian/04.flv'
file '/home/debian/05.flv'
file '/home/debian/06.flv'
file '/home/debian/07.flv'
file '/home/debian/08.flv'
file '/home/debian/09.flv'
file '/home/debian/10.flv'
file '/home/debian/11.flv'

Comment: what do you mean? what are those `file /home....` lines? file content? what is the problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your problem is generating those text in your example, what you need is nothing more than **seq** (looks similar with *sed* )

for example, I want to generate 70 lines like that:

```
seq --format="file '/home/debian/%02G.flv'" 70
```

if you want to put the output in a file:

```
seq --format="file '/home/debian/%02G.flv'" 70 > myFile.txt
```

Comment: i add a `'`,it is the result,seq --format="file '/home/debian/%02G.flv'" 70 > myFile.txt

Answer (score 0):

if it is a file with the contents given above try:

```
for ((i=0; i<=11; ++i)) do printf "file \'/home/debian/%0.2d.flv\n" $i; done
```